# PulseEffects and PulseAudio don't work as advertised

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, equalizer

I'm sorry. I don't know how else to phrase the title. I have Ubuntu 21.10 with Cinnamon. I have been having a hard time and have had a hard time with the whole kit and kaboodle since I installed Ubuntu 21.

Originally, I had reinstall both pulseeffects and pulseaudio. That still didn't really fix the problem. Then I deleted the pulseeffect and pulseaudio config directories. Then it started working. For the most part.

Now, my biggest problem is that I always have to launch pulseeffects to get the audio equalized for my computer. I could be wrong, but I don't believe that I should have to launch pulseeffects everytime the audio gets out of whack. I do have pulseaudio set to start as a service upon login so that is where the most confusing part is for me.

If the server is already running and the effects have been configured, then why do I still have to launch pulseeffects whenever I restart or relog?